# react all classNames are affected in map()

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const Home = () => {
    const getSongs = () => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/songs/')
            .then(res => setSongs(res.data))
    }

    let [songs, setSongs] = useState([])
    let [paused, setPause] = useState(true)

    useEffect(() => {
        getSongs()
    }, [])

    const toggleSong = (id) => {
        const x = document.getElementById(id)
        if (x.paused){
            x.play()
            setPause(false)
        } else {
            x.pause()
            setPause(true)
        }
    }

    // Got rid of the functions that are not needed

    return (
    <> 

        {
        songs.map(song =>
            (
            <div className='music-controller' key={song.id}>
                <div id={'songDiv'} style={{cursor: 'pointer'}} onClick={(e) => changeSongTime(e, song.id)}>
                    <div id={`songTime-${song.id}`}></div>
                </div>
                <div className="music-controller-body">
                    <div className="music-controller-header">
                        <h2>{song.title}</h2>
                        <p><small>{song.genre}</small></p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="controls">
                        // here <----------------------
                        <i unique={song.id} className={`fas fa-${paused ? 'play' : 'pause'}`} onClick={() => toggleSong(song.id)}></i>
                        
                        <audio id={song.id} onTimeUpdate={() => songTime(song.id)}>
                            <source src={`http://localhost:8000/api/songs/audio/${song.id}`} />
                        </audio>
                    </div>
                </div>      
            </div>
            ))}
    </>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Whenever I click on a specific i element all of the i elements that were not clicked on get changed too.. to put it simply when I click on the 1st i element only its className should change, but all of the i elements classNames are affected, what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you put console in toggleSong function at top and check if you are getting correct id. If you are not getting single Id then work is needed with onClick. So, after that also try passing id like this

`onClick={(song?.id) => toggleSong(song?.id)}`

then see console again and look for correct id if it is displayed or not. I think your className is not updating due to this issue.

One thing more you can try at end is replacing with this

```
const x = id; //without document.getElementById
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `event.target`

```
 const handlePlay = (song) => {
    song.play();
  };

  const handlePause = (song) => {
    song.pause();
  };

...

 <div className="controls">

    <i 
       onMouseOver={(e) => handlePlay(e.target)}
       onMouseLeave={(e) => handlePause(e.target)} 
       className={`fas fa-${paused ? 'play' : 'pause'}`} 
       onClick={() => toggleSong(song.id)}>
    </i>
    <audio id={song.id} onTimeUpdate={() => songTime(song.id)}>
    <source src={`http://localhost:8000/api/songs/audio/${song.id}`} />
    </audio>
</div>
```

I don't think `Toggle` would work in this case, an action should happen so it knows when it should stop.

Answer (score 0):

```
const toggleSong = (e, id) => {
        const x = document.getElementById(id)
        const button = e.currentTarget
        if (x.paused){
            x.play()
            button.className = 'fas fa-pause'
        } else {
            x.pause()
            button.className = 'fas fa-play'
        }
    }
```

---

```
<i unique={song.id} className='fas fa-play' onClick={(e) => toggleSong(e, song.id)}></i>
```

I fixed this by just getting the current target with event.currentTarget and change its className accordingly!